# How can you generate Mermaid from plantuml?

Tags: generator, documentation, plantuml, mermaid

I have to transfer plantuml diagrams to mermaid diagrams. Is there a way to somehow generate mermaid diagrams from plantuml diagrams? Thanks for answer

I've tried search it but nobody ever asked it here

Comment: What kinds of diagrams? PlantUML supports many diagrams that are not part of Mermaid, or there are differences. I don't know of any particular way to do this, but I do see why people want to. GitHub supports mermaid now. https://github.blog/2022-02-14-include-diagrams-markdown-files-mermaid/

Comment: Here's a blog entry that compares the two formats: https://www.dandoescode.com/blog/plantuml-vs-mermaid/

Comment: @Theromantus , did you ever figure out a way to do this that doesn't involve just manually updating the PlantUML diagrams as Mermaid?

Comment: No, I did mostly with regexes

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python to do some string replacements. However, you might need to adjust to meet your requirements.

```py
def convert_plantuml_to_mermaid(plantuml_code):
    conversion_table = {
        "@startuml": "",
        "@enduml": "",
        "->>": "->",
        "-->>": "-->",
        "-->>*": "-->*",
        "alt": "alt",
        "else": "else",
        "end": "end",
        "participant": "participant",
        "activate": "activate",
        "deactivate": "deactivate",
    }
    
    mermaid_code = []
    
    for line in plantuml_code.splitlines():
        for key, value in conversion_table.items():
            line = line.replace(key, value)
        mermaid_code.append(line)
    
    return "\n".join(mermaid_code)
```

I tried the following plantuml:

```
@startuml

autonumber

actor "用 户" as User
participant "webview" as webview #Orange
participant "网  页  后 端" as webview_service #Orange
participant "微  信  服  务" as wechat #Yellow
participant "微  信  小  程  序" as wmp
participant "微  信  小  程  序  后  端" as wmp_service

activate User

User -> wmp: 进 入 活 动 页 面

wmp -> webview: 加 载 活 动 网 页 url
activate webview
webview -> webview: 对 于 短 时 间 内 第 一 次 打 开 的 用 户 ， 展 示 授 权 页 面
webview_service -> wechat 
webview_service <- wechat: unionid

webview_service -> wmp_service: 使 用 appid/secret 换 取 server trust access token
webview_service <- wmp_service: access_token, refresh_token
webview_service -> wmp_service : 通 过 access_token 和 unionId 查 询 userId
alt 没 有 查 询 到 的 情 况
    webview_service <- wmp_service : null

    webview -> webview : 互 动

    webview -> wmp: 触 发 登 录 注 册 （ 中 奖 了 ！）

    wmp -> wmp_service : 登 录 注 册
    wmp <- wmp_service : jwt

    wmp -> webview: 回 调 网 页 ，不 带 用 户 信 息 参 数
    webview_service -> wmp_service: 通 过 access_token 和 unionId 查 询 userId
    webview_service <- wmp_service: userId (server to server talk)
else 查 询 到 了 userId
    webview_service <- wmp_service: userId (server to server talk)
end

webview_service -> webview_service: 保 存 (userId, 几 等 奖 ) 等 信 息

deactivate webview
```

And the converted mermaid:

```
sequenceDiagram
  autonumber

  actor User as 用户
  participant webview as webview #Orange
  participant webview_service as 第三方网页后端 #Orange
  participant wechat as 微信服务 #Yellow
  participant wmp as 微信小程序
  participant wmp_service as 微信小程序后端

  activate User

  User ->> wmp: 进入活动页面

  wmp ->> webview: 加载第三方活动网页URL
  activate webview
  webview ->> webview: 对于短时间内第一次打开的用户，展示授权页面
  webview_service ->> wechat: 获取用户的微信 unionid
  wechat -->> webview_service: unionid

  webview_service ->> wmp_service: 使用appid/secret换取server trust access token
  wmp_service -->> webview_service: access_token, refresh_token
  webview_service ->> wmp_service: 通过access_token和unionId查询userId
  alt 没有查询到的情况
    wmp_service -->> webview_service : null

    webview ->> webview: 互动

    webview ->> wmp: 触发登录注册（中奖了！）

    wmp ->> wmp_service: 登录注册
    wmp_service -->> wmp: jwt

    wmp ->> webview: 回调网页，不带用户信息参数
    webview_service ->> wmp_service: 通过access_token和unionId查询userId
    wmp_service -->> webview_service : userId (server to server talk)
  else 查询到了userId
    wmp_service -->> webview_service : userId (server to server talk)
  end

  webview_service ->> webview_service: 保存 (userId, 几等奖)等信息

  deactivate webview
```